# use capstrano deploy rails app to VPS appear config.eager_load is set to nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

use the capistrano to deploy rails app then appear

```
[deploy:migrate] Run `rake db:migrate`
00:37 deploy:migrating
      01 $HOME/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle exec rake db:migrate
      01 config.eager_load is set to nil. Please update your config/environments/*.rb files accordingly:
      01
      01   * development - set it to false
      01   * test - set it to false (unless you use a tool that preloads your test environment)
      01   * production - set it to true
      01
```

that in my code already set same to above

in SO can't find valid resolve

Answer (score 0):

You also have to set stage in `config/deploy/production.rb`

`set :stage,           :production`

You can also set branch to deploy by -

`set :branch,        :branch_name`

Or there might be a chance that its reading from cache so you can remove the directory and redeploy it.